# Python - Group multiple values from a column to create "Other" values

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I  have this dataset:

```
Field 
A
A
A
B
C
C
C
D
C
C
C
A
```

This has been read into `pandas` through the following code:

```
data = read_csv('data.csv', header=None)
print(data.describe())
```

How can I transform the column to get the below result?

```
Field 
A
A
A
Others
C
C
C
Others
C
C
C
A
```

I want to transform values B and D, since they have low frequency, to an aggregate value "Others".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Field': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C',
                             'D', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A']})

n = 2
counts = df['Field'].value_counts()
others = set(counts[counts < n].index)

df['Field'] = df['Field'].replace(list(others), 'Others')
```

**Result**

```
     Field
0        A
1        A
2        A
3   Others
4        C
5        C
6        C
7   Others
8        C
9        C
10       C
11       C
12       A
```

**Explanation**

- First get the counts of each value in `Field` via `value_counts`.
- Filter for values which occur less than `n` times. `n` is user-configurable.
- Finally replace those values with 'Others'.